# Should a process still run even if all it's relevant rpms are removed?

Tags: linux, rpm

For an application I have to install few rpms. I started the application ( a process for the application is running). Now, what if I remove all the rpms, without killing (or stopping) the process?

Will the process still run even though I uninstalled all relevant packages (rpms)? Or whether the un-installation of rpms, should kill the process automatically?

Comment: There is a difference between removing the rpm files, and uninstalling the package. Could you clarify which you are doing? Also, this question may be better suited to [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm removing rpm packages (through `rpm -e`). And, I'm not clear what is the difference between these two ?

Comment: One uninstalls the package, and the other removes the installation files (`rm foobar.rpm`)

Answer (score 1):

If the application in question is some sort of service (daemon) and is supposed to run in background, it usually will be stopped before removing files, from uninstall scripts in the rpm.

If the application in question is supposed to be run by the user manually, it usually will NOT be stopped before removing files, so after removing its rpm the process will still be running and possibly malfunctioning due to absent files. You'll have to kill it manually.

Why it is possible to have a process running when its executable is deleted? It turns out this is useful in a lot of contexts.

Comment: But, removing a package, should also kill the relevant process. Else the removal won't be said a clean removal.

Comment: @PabitraPati I'm not sure about that, for example, I would definitely not like if updating Firefox will abruptly kill my running browser.

Comment: But it's a fair expectation to close your browser, in order to update the packages properly. Anyway, the concern here is removal of package.And a removal means removal of all related libraries, sym tables etc... So, ideally, it should kill the process and then uninstall the packages.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling package (or application) is also a program, which is written by the developer of the application. There is no generic approach for uninstallation. A product should come with installation as well as uninstallation script/binary integrated.

But many times these uninstallation scripts are not cleanly written. A clean written uninstallation script should work as follow :-

1. first stop/kill all the relevant running processes, thus release the
   held locks (if not explicit lock release in each process's exit
   routine)
2. then uninstall the application
3. delete all temporary files/rules/configs created during the installation.